# How can I set intersection of two axes to (1,1) in a scatter plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I want is as the following sketchy figure:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you want two intersecting lines, you can do this with `geom_vline()` and `geom_hline()`

Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(-5,10), y=seq(-5,10))
qplot(x=x,y=y,data=df) + geom_vline(xintercept=1) + geom_hline(yintercept=1)
```

This makes:[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can hide the original axes from plot and draw you own with abline()

```
x <- rnorm(100,1)
y <- rnorm(100,1)

plot(x,y,axes=F)
abline(h=1)
abline(v=1)
```